# Player doesn't reload (download) when pause

Tags: video.js

I'm new to videojs, I trying to get a streaming video link then add it to the videojs, it's play ok but the problem is when I click pause button, I saw that the streaming bar stop too, and if I pause too long, it'll show the message "...Error network download...".

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

  <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>




</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">    
    <source src="https://r4---sn-oguesney.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=de55ccae62995d9e&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=153.161.152.244&ipbits=0&expire=1413906775&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=325F9294F189E8105901F78920E32FD23F9618D1.41C07D0C50787A79642DAD6F0DEEBA4D6B538BD3&key=ck2&mm=30&ms=nxu&mt=1413903097&mv=u&nh=IgpwcjAxLm5ydDE5KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&type=video/mp4;%20codecs=%22avc1.42001E,%20mp4a.40.2%22&quality=medium" type='video/mp4' />   
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After do the check, I saw that the preload worked on IE 11 but for the others, it't not!

**Update**

I saw that if use the Flash type instead of Html5, when press pause, the player still download the video for play later.

What going on?